# Remove all characters after certain sequence

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to remove all characters after the end of first number sequence.

Edit: (Sorry for ambiguity)

1. The string may or may not start with letters, but in case it starts
   the letters should be preserved.
2. After first sequence of numbers, everything should be removed.

   e.g. QWEE1232RTY -> QWE1232

   123RTY -> 123

   12342 -> 12342

   ```
   str.replaceAll("[^A-Z][^0-9]+","");
   ```

This should work but it's giving unexpected output and not printing the repeated "2".

[My ideone code for the attempt and it's respective outputs](http://ideone.com/XlQLgl)

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;    
    class Ideone
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            String str = "BCTC27452ASDFCCC";
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9]",""));
               // BCTC27452ASDFCCC
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9]$",""));
               // BCTC27452ASDFCCC
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z][^0-9]",""));
               // BCTC2745SDFCCC
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z][^0-9]+",""));     
            // Closest Output - "BCTC2745" (why 2nd "2" not printed)
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z][^0-9]*",""));
               // BCTC
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z][^0-9+]",""));
               // BCTC2745SDFCCC
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^A-Z][^0-9*]","")); 
               // BCTC2745SDFCCC    

            System.out.println("Expected Output: BTC27452");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just extract [`^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{5}`](https://regex101.com/r/aE5cN9/2)

Comment: Is your question why `2` is removed? Could you clarify the rules?

Comment: @Tushar The number of letters isn't fixed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I don't understand why it isn't printing the repeated digits.

Comment: `123RTY -> RTY` that can't be right...? "After first sequence of numbers, everything should be removed."

Comment: Corrected it. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean replace everything after a sequence of letters followed by a sequence of digits? Just look for that and replace the string with the match only:

```
str.replaceAll("^([A-Z]+[0-9]+).*","$1")
```

So basically you look for a sequence of at least one upper case character (`[A-Z]+`) followed by a sequence of at least one digit (`[0-9]+`) starting at the beginning of the input (`^`) and followed by anything ( `.*`). You capture the sequence into a group and replace the string with that group only (`$1` in the replacement string which refers to the first capturing group).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I letters before digits may or may not be present.  str.replaceAll("^[A-Z]*[0-9]+).*","$1") would do.